# Versioning problem

Tags: svn, versioning, mirroring

people. I hope you can help me.

In our development process we have a unix based file server with SFTP access **(let’s call  it A)**. This server store a large numer of xslt files we are working on.

The thing is that these files aren’t under version control system. So you can imagine this nightmare. We can’t setup repository on this server, we can only perform **create/read/update/delete** operations with these files.

So we have to find another approach. 
There is another server with full access **(let’s call it B)**. Is it possible to setup repository on B with background logic that on every repository operation will perform **download/merge/upload** operations related to server A?

There are two problems more:

1. All files on A lay in the same directory and  we want them to be structured on server B  in  a folder hierarchy.
2. Files on A can be changed by another team.

We are using Subversion. But maybe it is possible to realize rhs with another version control systems?

Thanks, Vova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no version control system will fly with your #2 problem (files on A can be changed by another team).  The rest of your requirements can be fulfilled with SVN and some simple scripts.  These could be DOS batch file scripts, python, perl, take your pick.

However, if you can't solve your #2 problem by ensuring the files on A are **never** changed by another team, I think what you're asking for is unfeasible.  All teams should work on the files in the repository on server B.

Anyhow, just my 2 cents.
-Doug

Comment: This combined with repository hooks will most likely do the trick. But you need to guarantee that the repository is always leading.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [svnsync](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt) to mirror a repository, or you could look at [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) to just do a update from it, and then perform some custom tasks afterwards.

Comment: One server is SFTP, not Subversion, so svnsync won't help here

Comment: Uh Sander, please read the question. He mentions Subversion at the end.

Comment: He's using Subversion on Server B. There's no version control on Server A

Comment: Yes, hence the reason I suggest it as a possibility (i.e. it can be installed). You aren't the OP; I don't see how you can make a judgement as to whether it's right for him; in fact not only do I not see how, I know that you can't. Regardless, it is not worth discussing with you further.